# Add anchor to url via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like my .htaccess file to transform urls like this:

```
http://localhost/onepage/
```

into urls like this:

```
http://localhost/onepage/#body
```

So `#body` suffix must be added to the urls.

The Apache version is 2.4. Rewrite module is on and works.

.Htaccess file is being parsed and is localized in the directory of index.php file.

There are not any virtual hosts on the port of 80. I use xampp on windows.

I tried such a code lines:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/onepage/ /onepage/#body  [NE,R]

    #RewriteRule ^/onepage /onepage/#body  [NE,R]
    #RewriteRule ^/onepage/$ /onepage/#body  [NE,R]
    #RewriteRule "^/onepage/$" /onepage/#body  [NE,R]
    #RewriteRule /?onepage/? /onepage/#body  [NE,R]
    #RewriteRule ^/?onepage/? /onepage/#body  [NE,R]
    #RewriteRule ^/?onepage/?$ /onepage/#body  [NE,R]
```

These commented lines was tested too, and did not succeed. These lines do simply nothing. How to get proper redirection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anchors (e.g. #body) are processed on the client side, not the server side.  Therefore, mod_rewrite can not add a #body anchor to the url

Comment: But there is adding anchors to the url in apache 2.4 documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: You are correct.  Sorry I hadn't noticed that. Use:
RewriteRule one_page /rewrite_test.html#body [NE,R]

Comment: But it should be the same address. I nearly resolved it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to match the leading slash in RewriteRule's pattern If you are testing these rules on an htaccess file , so remove the leading slash.

```
RewriteRule ^onepage/?$ /onepage#body [NE,R,L]
```

However, the rule above is still not correct, as the target url and the pattern is indentical and it will cause a redirect loop.

To solve this, you need to assign an extra path segment to your url

- /onepage/body/

Rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^onepage/body/?$ /onepage#body [NE,R,L]
```

Now you can easily redirect http://example.com/onepage/body to http://example.com/onepage#body

Comment: But I need to redirect `http://example.com/onepage/` to `http://example.com/onepage/#body`

Comment: Then you need to use javascript , this is not possible using htaccess as # is not implimented server side.

Comment: It is implemented on the server side. You can see in apache 2.4 documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this:

**.htaccess**

```
#adding query string to prevent looping so RewriteCond lets rewrite only at the first time since there is not "anchor" query string.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" !anchor
RewriteRule ^onepage/? /onepage/?anchor#body [QSA,NE,R=301]
```